# refresh a collection in propertygrid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

hay all. 
i am using property grid to add or remove an object to a collection.
but when the collectioneditor is closed only once the grid refreshes. 
after adding another object the grid wont get refresh.
the collection in a list.
i have seen many people with the same problem but no solutions.
thansk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface or use `ObservableCollection` class.
see the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=VS.85).aspx)

Comment: can you give me a nice example please?

Answer (score 2):

I realise i am very late to the party, but here it goes. I use this base class

```
public class CollectionEditorBase : CollectionEditor
{
    protected PropertyGrid ownerGrid;

    public CollectionEditorBase(Type type) : base(type) { }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        PropertyInfo ownerGridProperty = provider.GetType().GetProperty("OwnerGrid", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
        ownerGrid = (PropertyGrid)ownerGridProperty.GetValue(provider);

        return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
    }

    protected override CollectionForm CreateCollectionForm()
    {
        CollectionForm cf = base.CreateCollectionForm();
        cf.FormClosing += delegate(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            ownerGrid.Refresh();
        };

        return cf;
    }
}
```

Then you just create a new Collectioneditor based on that. It will automatically refresh the property grid when the collection form is closed.

Be aware though, this solution is reflecting into the internals of the property grid and can be broken at any time, but i have done this for a while now with no problem